# Is there a way to connect in a synchronous way to Couchbase Capella?

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I have a method that is overriding another one, the problem is that these methods return void, they are not asynchronous operations.
Is there a way to make the connection to my Couchbase Capella cluster in a synchronous way?

All of this is done in a 4.7.2 NET application with 3.14.11 Couchbase SDK

This is the code of my method (Using ASYNC, I know that I'm not modifying the methods to be async Task. I already did that and did not work, it is just an example for you to see what I need to do):

```
public override void MapProperties() {
            string endpoint = "connectionString";
            string username = "DBUserName";
            string password = "DBPassword";
            string bucketName = "BucketName";
            string scopeName = "ScopeName";
            string collectionName = "CollectionName";
            string key = "Document ID";

            var options = new ClusterOptions()
              .WithConnectionString(endpoint)
              .WithCredentials(username, password);

            var cluster = await Couchbase.Cluster.ConnectAsync(options);
            var bucket = await cluster.BucketAsync(bucketName);
            var scope = bucket.Scope(scopeName);
            var collection = scope.Collection(collectionName);

            var getResult = await collection.GetAsync(key);
            var resultContent = getResult.ContentAs<JObject>();
    }
```

This is overriding a method in a parent class declared as:

```
public abstract void MapProperties();
```

My question is, is there a way to do the same but in a synchronic way?

Just to clarify, the credentials are okay, the issue is not related to that

I tried to modify every method from void to async Task but didn't work.

I also tried to use `WaitUntilReady` but it keeps saying that the Cluster is not bootstrapped yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Couchbase .NET SDK 3.x, it's all-in on async. So, technically, no, there isn't a way. I'd be surprised if that code compiled, since you are using `await` in a method that isn't `async`.

There is a project from CenterEdge called [CenterEdge.Async](https://github.com/CenterEdge/CenterEdge.Async), which can help you run async code from sync code.

However, I'd also recommend checking out [Stephen Cleary's blog, book, etc](https://blog.stephencleary.com/), to learn more about async/await, and see if there's any way to make your code async. In the long run, I think that's the way to go.